# How can I pass an object as an url variable in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python and Flask. I am currently working on a project where I need to render different pages for different actions but they both need to have access to the one same object.

for example:

```
@app.route("/", methods =['GET','POST'])
def funtionA()
    objs = somefunction() // returns an object list
    render_template("/results/'+objs+'")

@app.route("/results/<objs>", methods =['GET','POST'])
def functionB(objs)
    for obj in objs
       print(objs[i].attr)
```

I am able to pass string, integer even path as a parameter. I couldn't find any references to see if passing an object is doable or not. Appreciate your responses!

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the data you need pass from one view to the other? Is the data coming out of a DB?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an application global. This is accessible via `flask.g`

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-globals

> Flask provides you with a special object that ensures it is only valid for the active request and that will return different values for each request.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like what you need is to use [flask url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for)

```
@app.route("/", methods =['GET','POST'])
def funtionA()
    objs = somefunction() // returns an object list
    return redirect(url_for('app.functionB', objs=objs))

@app.route("/results/<objs>", methods =['GET','POST'])
def functionB(objs)
    for obj in objs
       print(objs[i].attr)  
    return "something {}".format(objs)
```

not also that you views functions should always return a response

it's one of the solutions to your problem, hope it will help